# Sysprep system started up

Tags: imaging, sysprep, ghost

We sysprep'd our newest xp install and restarted to image it. Our tech missed getting it to boot into the usb drive for imaging. Is there anyway to leave the install now without it giving a bootup error ie: 'Windows did not shutdown properly' so when we do image it, it will not do that everytime we go to reimage onto a new machine?

Edit:
I did just try "shift+ctrl+F3" at the 'Welcome Screen' and it didn't do anything.

Comment: possibly by doing an offline edit of the disk/registry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reboot after the shutdown after running sysprep, you'll have to run through the sysprep process again.  Any time windows boots after being sysprepped, it automatically begins to unpack.  After sysprep runs and the workstation shuts down, you'll have to have some sort of alternative boot process to capture the image from the target workstation.  It sounds like you already have the PE boot environment on a flash drive.  One trick is to turn off all boot methods except for flash drive in the BIOS.  This way, you're SURE to hit the flash drive next time around.  Make this BIOS change after you've shutdown and before you start up the first time after sysprep runs!

I hope this is the answer you were looking for.... let me know if it isn't.